# Changing Link and Font colors within ID's

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of replicating the Google homepage (for practice) and am running into a few problems.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdaless/kTn7j/

I am trying to make my text color: white, and text-decoration to none.  No matter where I put these two commands, they do not change.  I don't know if I am having an inheritance issue or what my problem may be.  From my understanding, I thought I could put:

```
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
```

in either my `#nav-container` id or `#navlist`.

Comment: You need to target link http://jsfiddle.net/kTn7j/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both removing the underline and making the text color white apply to the anchor tag

```
ul#navlist li a{
     color:#fff;
     text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
#nav-container ul li a{

color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kTn7j/3/)

Answer (score 1):

When making list-based menus, all styling that is not position-related should go on the A-tag, not the LI and use `display:block`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this selector:

```
#navlist li
```

To this (target the a tag)

```
#navlist li a
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is present inside the `anchor` tag, hence the css should be applied for the `a` tag. Try this css

```
#nav-container {
    background-color:#000;  
}

#navlist li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;

}
#navlist li a{
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
}
```

check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/KnS8s/